# How to connect Nest-Ts gateway socket/server to client python3?

Tags: python-3.x, react-native, sockets, nestjs

I’m new self-taught Dev, I also don’t master very well English. I haven’t got chance to be at school so I’m self-taught for everything. sorry for my question maybe stupid.

I have Nest-Ts with a @WebSocketGateway works properly with react front-end but now I want to connect it to my desktop python3 UI App but I don’t really now how to match it with Nest-Ts gateway entry points. in my nestts I have this

```
/// handle new connection
async handleConnection(client) {
/// some console logs here
}
```

Then incomings messages and outgoing messages like follow

```
@SubscribMessage('channel')
async onChanel(user, content) {
user.broadcast.emit('channel',
content);}
```

It works as expected but in python3 client i have this:

```
def start(self):
    try:
        print('trying to connect to 
        host, port')
        self.socket.connect((
        self.host, self.port))
        print('successful connected 
        to host, port)
     except...
```

this print connected but the back-end nest does make any signe
And when I try to send something using

```
self.socket.send('channnel',
'some text here');// utf-8 encode
```

python3 throw an error Bad request.
What should do instead ??

Comment: Change to self.sock.send('channel');// utf-8 and not more issue but I can’t have it from my Nest backend and no event a console.log() whether a new client is connected or not

Comment: For the websocket adapter, are you using socket.io (default) or websocket/ws?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel > not the default socket.io. The default (socket.io) is used for the front-end PYTHON but not in Nestts the back-end and I know it would have works if I did used it default socket.io in Nestts. Is there WebSocket for python front-end ?. I’ve used WebSocketGateway from my understanding, WebSocketGateway listening to the same port as the App to the domain that will be assign to the app at the hoster. By the way, which one is the best option ?? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the regular websocket library for python is. But if you're using a socket.io-client in your python application you should be connecting to a socket.io server. As for which is better, they each have their own pros and cons.

Comment: Does it means that I won’t succeed connecting it over WebSocket to socket.io? If yes, is there a possibility to make a socket.io listening to the some port as router of applications ?

Comment: But why does it works with react socket.io-client??

Comment: If it works from a react with socket.io-client then I'd assume you _are_ using socket.io on the server. I'd need to see how your `bootstrap` of your server looks to know for sure. If you're successfully connecting, it may just be a matter of how the request is being sent.

Comment: It works perfectly from react. I can even send a message to particular person with my own way of doing it. Let make a answer with full code from Nest to reac-native (Mobile App)

Answer (score 0):

this is my Nest main.ts file contents

```
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
   app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
   /*  app.enableCors({
   origin: false,
   });*/
await app.listen(3003);
console.log(`your app is running on ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

then the contents of my gateway.ts file

```
 @Injectable()
 @WebSocketGateway()

 export class EventsGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, 
 OnGatewayDisconnect {
 constructor(
    @InjectModel('Iddata') private iddataModel: Model<Iddata>,
    @InjectModel('Chats') private chatsModel: Model<Chats>,
 ) { }

@WebSocketServer() server;


socid: string;
ids = [];

async handleConnection(client) {
    // signaler
    this.socid = client.id;

    console.log(client.id);

}

@SubscribeMessage('my_channel')
async onChanel(@MessageBody() data: any): Promise<any> {
    data.id = `${this.socid}`
    this.ids.push(data)
    console.log(this.ids);
    console.log(data);
    this.server.emit('users', `${data.chanel} is online`);
    return `hello ${data.chanel}! You're successfully connected`;
}


async handleDisconnect(client) {
    // notify a client is disconnected
    const prevIndex = this.ids.findIndex(item => item.id === client.id);
    this.ids.splice(prevIndex, 1);

}


@SubscribeMessage('chat')
async onChat(client, message) {
    client.broadcast.emit(message.tar_getfone, message);
    const vou = this.ids.filter((item) => item.chanel === 
    message.tar_getfone)
    if (vou.length == 0) {
        console.log('sending to the data base')
        this.postChatId(message)

    }
}
```

then react expo mobile app code hook

the listener is in adifferent file because i have two differents files or code need to be notify whent ther is new message to pop up notification but it connect as two different client to the server, i created the listener some where else for all to fetch connection from there here is the bind or listener:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

export const ENDPOINT = 'http://192.168.1.101:3003';


export const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);


export default socket;
```

then here one of the chats receptions file:

```
import { socket } from "../constants/onLine";

let idf = 1;
// recieve message a save it into local storage
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(`${user.phone_number}`, function (data) {
        idf++
        console.log('message', data.phone_number);
        (async () => {
            await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
                content: {
                    title: data.phone_number,
                    body: data.body_word,
                    data: { data: '' },
                },
                trigger: { seconds: 1 },
            });
        })();

        idb.transaction(function (txn) {
            txn.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO id_data(lo_go, tar_getfone, my_getfone, sms_state, body_word, create_tim) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                [data.lo_go, data.tar_getfone, data.my_getfone, data.sms_state, data.body_word, data.create_tim],
                (txn, results) => {
                    console.log('created', results.rowsAffected);
                    setMaxw((d) => d + 1)

                })

        });


        data.id = idf

        messages.push(data)
        setMessages(messages);
 // sending confirmation to the server data recieved
 
        socket.emit('conf', {
            "tar_getfone": data.phone_number,
            "my_getfone": data.tar_phone_number,
            "conf": 'ok',
            "create_tim": data.create_tim
        });
    });
    // listening to a confimation for any message i sent to someone
    socket.on(`${user.phone_number}ok`, function (data) {
        console.log(data.conf);

    });
}, [])


useEffect(() => {

    // listening to new user joined this for test only

     
    socket.on('users', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

// listening in cas of an exception

    socket.on('exception', function (data) {
        console.log('error', data);
    });


 // listening to a user disconnection this for test only
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });

}, [])


useEffect(() => {
    console.log('connecting')
    { if im connected i will sen my phone number for handle 
       disconnection a and save my present so that, messages destined 
     to me coms directly instead of going to the database to wait for me
     }
    socket.on("connect", function () {
        socket.emit('my_channel', {
            chanel: `${user.phone_number}`,
            id: ''
        }, response => {

            console.log(response)

        })

    });

}, [])
```

for my desktop app python frond-end it works also with my python server project socket.io
but not with Nest let post that also fully:

```
import threading
import socket

class Send(threading.Thread):
    #Sending thread 

    def __init__(self, sock, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.sock = sock
        self.name = name

     def run(self):
         # Send message to server  
         self.sock.sendall('{}: {}'.format(self.name, message).encode('ascii'))



 class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.name = None
    self.messages = None
    self.atestex = True

    


 def start(self):
    """
    Establishes the client-server connection. 
    creates and starts the Send and Receive threads, 
    """
    try:
        print('Trying to connect to {}:{}...'.format(self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        print('Successfully connected to {}:{}'.format(self.host, self.port))


        # Create send and receive threads
       # send = Send(self.sock, self.name)
       # receive = Receive(self.sock, self.name)
       # but testing with nest im not gonna use it yet

        # Start send and 
        receive = "hello";

        chanel = "my_channel"
        self.sock.send(chanel.encode('utf-8'))

        return receive
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print('could not connect !!!')


class ManageUersPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    
        self.configure(bg='Tomato')

        self.atester = False





    def starter():
        global client
        client = Client('192.xxx.x.x', 3003)
        receive = client.start()
        client.messages = messages
        if receive:
            receive.messages = messages
            self.atester = True
            
        else:
            messages.insert(END, 'conection lost please try again!')
```

that is it!!! Thanks

Comment: In the future, add on information to your question, not as a new answer, as it's not really an answer to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Python's `socket` package is a raw socket/websocket package, whereas you're using [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) on the NestJS Server and the React Web Application. You'll want to use the [python socket.io package](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in your python package, because socket.io servers expect to be used with socket.io clients

Comment: Thanks but seem my question is not clear explained to make sense for you to understand because  I’m not getting well what you’re trying to explain in your answer. Actually, I’m not using socket.io in my Nestts project. it is WebSocketGateway I don’t know if the same thing but that is what I’ve used in Nest. And for react it is a Mobile phone Application rather then web application, however I’m using socket.io-client for react and socket.io for Python3.

Comment: `@WebSocketGateway()` is a decorator in Nest to say "this class sets up listeners for the web socket server". It's called a `gateway`. `socket.io` is a websocket engine, and is by default, the websocket adapter NestJS  uses when you use `@WebSocketGateway()`. If you were using a different websocket adapter, it would be seen in your `bootstrap` method by calling [`app.useWebSocketAdapter()`](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter), but as you don't, you actual **are** using Socket.IO. I should know, I'm on the NestJS core team.

Comment: And the fact that `socket.io-client` works from the React application confirms that you are indeed using socket.io as the websocket server, because otherwise the websocket requests would fail, and there would be no response.  Socket.IO  is its own engine, and regular  websocket requests do not work well with the socket.io engine, just as socket.io requests do not work well with a regular websocket server.

Comment: Okay so actually what should I use in my python to get this works? socket.io or socket.io-client if it does exist in python ? Or no event a way to get this works together ?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, use the `python socket.io pakage`. That's a link to their docs and setting everything up

Comment: Is that different from this :
import socket?

Comment: Yes. That's python's general websocket implementation.

Comment: Ahhhhhh okay now get everything clear! Let me check it up thanks